# apache2 service not restart from apache2 server using php

Tags: 14.04, bash, apache2

I have created the bash script which restart the apache2 service using php code but Issue is that whenever I execute script using web, apache2 service going to stop instead restart, so that web application also stop then I've must start the service using ssh !

Is there any solution or troubleshooting of that?

Comment: Bash script, or PHP? What is the contents?

Comment: On script, l've write the command for restart apache2 service and script execute from php web application.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help unless you share actual script contents with us.